# Incremental training of Neural Networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, continuous-data

*Is it valid to train a neural network over and over again with new arriving data (including pruning after each new training)?*

I plan to collect data for a period of time, train/cv/test the networ, then again collect new data and train the existing and already trained network with the new data.

The time series prediction setup, e.g. described [here](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/tutorials/StockMarketPredictionTutorial.html), doesn't fit I think, as the input and the output isn't the same data type, i.e. the input features are volume based count of a data stream and the output is a class label, so I cannot just "move the data to the left".

My searches on Google yielded mainly results regarding "incremental vs. batch" training of the weights of a model or incremental growing of the hidden layer. [This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.52.9724&rep=rep1&type=pdf) seems to be what I'm looking for, but I'm still not completely confident about the usage of recurrent neural networks.

I could also create a new network for each time period, but thus I'd lose the knowledge gathered from the previous time periods.

*So what do you suggest?*

Comment: If you use regularization in the training then you don't need to prune.  The big ones are finicky, so getting them to work well with continuous training can be a challenging proposition.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to use Transfer Learning Techniques. Basically, it transfers the knowledge in your big and old dataset to your fresh and small dataset.

Try reading: A Survey on Transfer Learning and the algorithm TrAdaBoost.

Answer (score 1):

This branch of ML is referred to as [Continual Learning](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/24315/23503) (or Incremental Learning). It is effectively multi-task transfer learning, where the tasks come sequentially, and we wish to use an architecture which does not "catastrophically forget" the information from the previous tasks. See the following paper:

[*Continual Lifelong Learning with Neural Networks: A Review*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.07569.pdf) (2019)

And the following related questions:

- https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/14047/what-are-the-state-of-the-art-approaches-for-continual-learning-with-neural-netw
- https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/23567/is-continuous-learning-possible-with-a-deep-convolutional-neural-network-withou/24529#24529